# how many spark execturos runs for the below configuration and how can i tune it.?

Tags: apache-spark

I am using spark standalone cluster and below are my spark-env properties.

```
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_INSTANCES=432
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=24
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY=36G
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=24G
```

I have 6 worker nodes and if i tried to run a job that has huge size of files and joins, it is getting stuck and failing. I could see 6 executors for the job with 24GB.

Could you please provide me any links or details to tune it and understand the worker nodes and executors concepts. I referred one cloudera blog, but that is more about yarn. But, i need it for spark standalone cluster

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had similar problems as yours, and you can refer to below articles, which I've bookmarked after reading a lot of tuning articles. Hope it helps.

- [Spark official doc: Tuning Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html)
- [virdata: Tuning Spark Streaming for Throughput](http://www.virdata.com/tuning-spark/)
- [cloudera: How-to: Tune Your Apache Spark Jobs](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-1/)